# Connection of Postgres with Python on Shell

Tags: python, postgresql, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
import sys
import psycopg2.extras


def main():

        #from config import config

        conn=psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",user="postgres",database="firstdb");

        cur=conn.cursor('cursor_unique_name', cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
        cur.execute("select * from data")
        row_count = 0
        for row in cur:
                row_count += 1
                #print "abc"
                print "row: %s          %s\n" % (row_count, row)
                print "hello";



        print "Hello there I am working Man!!!...";

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Can someone Help me rectifying the error in this script since I am not able to print rows through this script?

Only the last Print executes once I do `python firstname.py` .

I have made changes in `pg_hba.conf` as suggested by other answers but still no success!

Comment: not much of a postgres man myself, but have you tried replacing `for row in cur` with `for row in cur.fetchall()` ?

Comment: yes!! I did so but that too didn't worked at all

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are seeing suggests that you have an empty database.  I was unable to reproduce a problem with the following procedure:

1. Create a database

   ```
   $ createdb -U postgres firstdb
   ```
2. Create a table

   ```
   $ psql -U postgres firstdb
   firstdb=# create table data (id int, name varchar(20));
   ```
3. Insert some data:

   ```
   firstdb=# insert into data (id, name) values (1, 'alice');
   INSERT 0 1
   firstdb=# insert into data (id, name) values (2, 'bob');
   INSERT 0 1
   firstdb=# insert into data (id, name) values (3, 'mallory');
   INSERT 0 1
   ```
4. Run your code

   ```
   $ python dbtest.py
   row: 1          [1, 'alice']

   hello
   row: 2          [2, 'bob']

   hello
   row: 3          [3, 'mallory']

   hello
   Hello there I am working Man!!!...
   ```

It seems to be working as designed.

Comment: Hye as mentioned in the question I am working over db name "firstdb" and using table "data".

Comment: yes, exactly as you see here in this answer. Did you have a question?